# Injecting JQuery into Amazon.com pages using PhantomJS causes problems with JQuery

Tags: jquery, phantomjs

I'm opening any page in the Amazon.com domain (for example "http://www.amazon.com") and then attempting to inject JQuery like this:

```
var injected = page.injectJs('jquery-1.7.1.js');
console.log("jquery was injected successfully: " + injected);
```

This code will print `true` to the console. However, trying to access `$(document)` from within `page.evaluate()` like this:

```
page.onLoadFinished = function (status) {
    var results = page.evaluate(function() {
        $(document);    
    });

phantom.exit();
};
```

Will print `TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function` to the console.

This code works with most other domains I've tried with. I noticed that Amazon seems to have its own version of JQuery that it loads and I wonder if it might be conflicting with the JQuery version I'm loading somehow. Any ideas?

Comment: Please tag questions like this as javascript as well (next time).

Comment: What happens when you use the non alias? `jQuery(document)` for example.

Comment: It works (thanks!). But I don't understand why. Does anyone know?

Comment: It's very possible that Amazon is already using the $ alias for something else in their client code.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to put jQuery in noConflict mode with an alternate variable name like so:

```
var results = page.evaluate(function () {
    $jq = window.jQuery;
    $jq.noConflict();

    console.log("Title: " + $jq('title').text());
});
```

Worked for me! Hope it works for you! :)